# Trying to connect Huawei IAP SDK for Inapp payments - 6003 error

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to connect Huawei IAP SDK for Inapp payments. After adding an app in developer console and some inapp items, I tried to run Iap.getIapClient(activity).isBillingSupported method, but got **com.huawei.hms.support.api.iap.json.IapApiException: 6003** error. Can't get any information about that status code, what does it mean. Does anybody know something about it?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and here is the fix. The error clearly says that `6003` -> `StatusCode.CERT_FINGERPRINT_ERROR`. It looks like Huawei can't validate the originality of the app, because of the missing certificate.

You either didn't added `agconnect` to your project or you're running in a different build type (like debug, that was my issue because I added `agconnect` several days ago).

If you didn't added the `agconnect` to your project, make sure you add it. There is an official tutorial how to add it, but here is it in a nutshell:

First of all you need to add the `agconnect` dependency to your project, download the `agconnect-services.json` file from Huawei's Developer (from your App). You need to obtain a `SHA256` fingerprint with `keytool` and add this long fingerprint to your Huawei's Developer field.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/iap-configuring-appGallery-connect#certificate

If you added `agconnect` (like I did several days ago) and the error persisted, it was because you were running in `debug` or any other build type which is different than what your official release. If you're running in `debug` make sure you add the signing certificate to your `debug` build type.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('C:\\path-to-your\project\signing-certificate.jks')
        keyAlias 'aliasOfYourCertificate'
        keyPassword 'theKeyPasswordOfCertificate'
        storePassword 'theStorePasswordOfCertificate'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

So the key here is adding the `signingConfig` to your `debug` build type (if you're running in debug).

Comment: You can also add the debug certificate fingerprint into AppGallery Connect Project settings and download the agconnect-services.json again.
On emulator the error keeps coming even after right configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the certificate fingerprint is correctly configured on HUAWEI Developer. Sign into HUAWEI Developer, go to Management Center > My Products, and select the services that require fingerprint certificate. In the product service list, check whether the SHA256 certificate fingerprint is same as the one you obtained. If not, modify the SHA256 certificate fingerprint, then clear the HMS cache.
2. If the issue persists, contact HUAWEI support.

Resource: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/hms/catalog/huaweiid.html?page=hmssdk_huaweiid_api_reference_errorcode